# Multiple expressions in one Regular expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, c#-4.0, regex-negation

I had written the below regular expression

string validnumber = @"^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{7}$";

This will allow the numbers like "AA1234567".

I want to write the regular expression to allow below formats "AA1234567-12345" or "AA1234567" in one expression.

Can anyone please help me how can i write that

Comment: `^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{7}(?:-[0-9]+)?$`

Comment: What is the rule  here? Have you tried updating the pattern? What didn't work?

Comment: it was allowing "QQ1234567" format but not wokring for "QQ1234567-12345" format. @revo

Comment: i would like to allow both formats  "AA1234567-12345" or "AA1234567" strings in one regualr expression @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Nothing is pulled off your regex. I just added one optional non-capturing group and it works. Re-check the way you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `"^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{7}(?:-[0-9]{5})?$`